# No module named clr

Tags: python, python.net

I have installed pythonnet with `pip install pythonnet` and I am trying to use clr by import clr.
However, I get an error saying `"no module named clr."`
Is there a problem with the directory I am working? My python code is in desktop and I use pycharm professional.

Comment: Did you install the module in the same interpreter your PyCharm project is using?

Comment: That was the problem, it worked thanks so much